# Regex to Remove Name, Address, Designation from an email text Python

Tags: python, regex, email, regex-group

I have a sample text of an email like this. I want to keep only the body of the text and remove names, address, designation, company name, email address from the text. So, to be clear, I only want the content of each mails between the From Dear/Hi/Hello to  Sincerely/Regards/Thanks. How to do this efficiently using a regex or some other way

```
Subject: [EXTERNAL] RE: QUERY regarding supplement 73

Hi Roger,

Yes, an extension until June 22, 2018 is acceptable.

Regards, 
Loren


Subject: [EXTERNAL] RE: QUERY regarding supplement 73

Dear Loren, 
We had initial discussion with the ABC team us know if you would be able to extend the response due date to June 22, 2018.


Best Regards,
Mr. Roger
Global Director
roger@abc.com
78 Ford st.





Subject: [EXTERNAL] RE: QUERY regarding supplement 73

responding by June 15, 2018.check email for updates

Hello,
John Doe 
Senior Director
john.doe@pqr.com




Subject: [EXTERNAL] RE: QUERY regarding supplement 73


Please refer to your January 12, 2018 data containing labeling supplements to add text regarding this
symptom. We are currently reviewing your supplements and have
made additional edits to your label.

Feel free to contact me with any questions.

Warm Regards,
Mr. Roger
Global Director
roger@abc.com
78 Ford st.


Center for Research
Office of New Discoveries
Food and Drug Administration 
Loren@mno.com
```

From this text I only want as OUTPUT :

```
    Subject: [EXTERNAL] RE: QUERY regarding supplement 73
Yes, an extension until June 22, 2018 is acceptable.
We had initial discussion with the ABC team us know if you would be able to extend the response due date to June 22, 2018.
responding by June 15, 2018.check email for updates
Please refer to your January 12, 2018 data containing labeling supplements to add text regarding this
    symptom. We are currently reviewing your supplements and have
    made additional edits to your label. 
    Feel free to contact me with any questions.
```

Comment: did my answer below help you with the problem outlined in your question?

Comment: I will check man. Thanks for replying. I will check and let you know

Comment: I'm still curious if this answer work for you or not.

Comment: It actually is not working because it's file specific. I have written a few regex where if a string starts with a keyword, it has to be ignored. It's pretty similar to that

Comment: Thanks for the input.  It near impossible to design a solution for a problem with only one example pulled from a larger dataset containing items that fall outside of the parameters for the sample.  My answer was designed for the sample and not the entire dataset, which is what I stated.

Comment: Thanks I have marked it as helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an answer that works for your current input.  The code ***will have*** to be adjusted when you process examples that fall outside the parameters outlined in the code below.

```
with open('email_input.txt') as input:

   # List to store the cleaned lines
   clean_lines = []

   # Reads until EOF
   lines = input.readlines()

   # Remove some of the extra lines
   no_new_lines = [i.strip() for i in lines]

   # Convert the input to all lowercase
   lowercase_lines = [i.lower() for i in no_new_lines]

   # Boolean state variable to keep track of whether we want to be printing lines or not
   lines_to_keep = False

   for line in lowercase_lines:
      # Look for lines that start with a subject line
      if line.startswith('subject: [external]'):
         # set lines_to_keep true and start capturing lines
         lines_to_keep = True

      # Look for lines that start with a salutation
      elif line.startswith("regards,") or line.startswith("warm regards,") \
          or line.startswith("best regards,") or line.startswith("hello,"):
          # set lines_to_keep false and stop capturing lines
          lines_to_keep = False

    if lines_to_keep:
        # regex to catch greeting lines
        greeting_component = re.compile(r'(dear.*,|(hi.*,))', re.IGNORECASE)
        remove_greeting = re.match(greeting_component, line)
        if not remove_greeting:
           if line not in clean_lines:
               clean_lines.append(line)


for item in clean_lines:
    print (item)

    # output 
    subject: [external] re: query regarding supplement 73

    yes, an extension until june 22, 2018 is acceptable.
    we had initial discussion with the abc team us know if you would be able to 
    extend the response due date to june 22, 2018.
    responding by june 15, 2018.check email for updates
    please refer to your january 12, 2018 data containing labeling supplements 
    to add text regarding this symptom. we are currently reviewing your 
    supplements and have made additional edits to your label.
    feel free to contact me with any questions.
```